What are non-archimedean norms on $\mathbb{R}$, whose restriction to $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial?
I wonder if there is any classification result on non-archimedean norms on $\mathbb{R}$, with trivial restriction to $\mathbb{Q}$? Any references or examples would be welcomed!
Some examples of such norms can be defined as follows: for each transcendence number $t$, we consider $\mathbb{Q}(t)\subset \mathbb{R}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(T)$. Fix a prime number $p$ and define a norm on $f(T)\in Q[T]$ by $|f(T)|=p^{ \deg(f)}$. Extend this norm from $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Then this defines a non-trivial non-archimedean norm on $\mathbb{R}$, whose restriction to $\mathbb{Q}$ is trivial.

Why can you extend such a norm from $\mathbb Q(t)$ to $\mathbb R$?

@LSpice Given a normed field $(K,v)$ and an extension field $K\subseteq L$, can't one use Zorn's lemma to find a norm on $L$ that extends the norm on $K$? (Not uniquely, of course.) In this instance, the OP is defining a norm on $\mathbb Q(t)$ (although the significance of $p$ being a prime is unclear, any $p>1$ will do), and they're fixing an embedding $\mathbb Q(t)\hookrightarrow\mathbb R$. So there is a norm on $\mathbb R$ extending the norm on $\mathbb Q(t)$. Of course, it will be unrelated to the usual norm on $\mathbb R$.

@LSpice It is a nontrivial fact that any nonarchimedean norm on any field can be extended to any extension, algebraic or not. It's very noncanonical but always exists.

As a field, $\mathbb R$ is immensely complicated (infinite transcendence degree over the prime field, etc.). I think the question is unapproachable even in much simpler cases, like for valuations on $\mathbb Q(x,y)$. Can we give a classification for this ring, at least for rank 1 valuations?

@Wojowu What about valuations on $\overline{\mathbb Q(x)}$?

Every construction I can think of uses the axiom of choice. I would not be surprised it if were consistent with ZF (without AC) that no such norm on $\mathbb{R}$ exists.
